# Puppeteer page.content() - writing resolved promise into list

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, promise, puppeteer

I am trying to write a page's content into a list with puppeteer.

My problem is too basic for other solutions out there. The reason I am failing is because I am too ignorant to get the resolved promise from an asynchronous function. I looked at the js documentation, I looked at similar answers, to no avail.

I also tried multiple ways to resolve the `page.content()` promise within the asynchronous function, still failing miserably.

```
async function getPageContent(website) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(website, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
  const websiteContent = await page.content();
  await browser.close();

  return websiteContent;
}

var htmlList = [];
var ws = "https://www.google.com/";
var googleHtml = getPageContent(ws);

htmlList.push(googleHtml);

console.log(htmlList);
```

The result is `[Promise { pending }]`, which I understand is due to the promise status being unresolved. What I would like is the actual string of google's DOM.

Thank you for any help in this specific promise / async / puppeteer crash course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to await `getPageContent`:

```js
var htmlList = [];
var ws = "https://www.google.com/";
var googleHtml = await getPageContent(ws);
```

Comment: works like a charm, thank you very much. Also for the kind words

Comment: At least, for some reason it appeared to work. Now it says "await is only valid in async function" (which makes sense, after reading into it). I know, I could chuck it into another async function, but what is the correct way to get the value out on the top level, if any?

Comment: That means that you can only use an await inside an async function. If have to check how to do async in the framework you are using. If it's just a script you can do something like `(async() => { /*your code*/})();`